# How to preserve userscript modifications in Chrome after an asynchronous content update on an .aspx webpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, tampermonkey, dopostback

I'm trying to automate the workflow of a webpage for my company's inventory system. The page is generated by the server-side logic of an ASP.Net page, which I don't have access to.  The page has several fields on it to allow you to enter a new container barcode, the item that should go in the container, etc.  Each of these fields has an `onchange` event listener hooked up to it which calls the page's `__doPostBack()` function to verify the entered data.  If the data is verified, the page code is re-served with the data entered so far, and focus is set to the next field on the form.

I want to automate this page with a userscript in Chrome.  I started by using ViolentMonkey to inject a custom script, but I could only get the script to trigger on the initial load, not after each data entry.  After this, I tried using Chrome Local Overrides to change `__doPostBack()` to try to capture the data I need to automate the page. That also only works once; after a field is filled and loses focus and new HTML is served, it overwrites Chrome's local copy.

I think that my problems are being caused by an asynchronous refresh of the entire page contents, which wipes out the injected userscript and Chrome's Local Override without triggering the normal page refresh listeners in Chrome Overrides or ViolentMonkey to re-inject the modified code.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how I could modify the JavaScript in such a way that it would persist after the page content is replaced with new HTML?

P.S. I don't think the code itself is relevant to this particular problem, but if anyone thinks it would be helpful to share a limited section of the client-side code, let me know.

**Edit 1**: Here's a more in-depth view of what I'm trying to accomplish, and the progress I've made so far.  For reference, the form looks like this:

**My Original Plan**

1. The user loads the page. ViolentMonkey injects a userscript which issues a series of prompts, collecting data on the range of new barcodes that the user would like entered into the system. (Specifically, the barcode prefix, the starting barcode number, and the ending barcode number.)  This values are stored in `localStorage`.
2. After this data has been collected and validated by the user, the page loads normally. For reference, the form looks something like this:

[image: sample.png]

3. The user fills out the fields as normal. After each field is filled out (with the exception of the Container Description field), the page pushes focus to the next field. (For example: `<script language="javascript">  try { document.getElementById('txtContDesc').focus() } catch (e) { }  </script>`. The id of the field to focus is dynamically changed via the server logic.)
4. I need to collect the User Badge, Container Type, and Destination Barcode values so that I can refill them later when I automate the form.  My original plan was to add a `onfocus` event listener to the Container Description field, since focus will be shifted to it once the Destination Barcode field has been verified. I will know at this point that the user has successfully entered a valid entry for each of the fields above the Container Description field, and I would then be able to collect these values and store them in `localStorage`.
5. Once I have all the data needed for the form, I would pilot the form using the userscript in ViolentMonkey and the data stored in `localStorage`, to persist data across page refreshes.

**Other Alternatives:**

The `eventListener` idea on an element doesn't work, because ASP.NET updates the page with fresh code every time a field is verified, wiping out the listener.  It also doesn't trigger a refresh, so ViolentMonkey doesn't rerun my userscript.

My other thought was to modify `doPostBack()`.  The `doPostBack()` function looks like this (as far as I can tell):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var theForm = document.forms['formNewContainer'];
      if (!theForm) {
         theForm = document.formNewContainer;
      }
      function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
          console.log("Form submitted");
      }
</script>
```

It is called on verified fields with the following `onchange` handler:

```
onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$newContPage$txtBarcode\',\'\')', 0)"
```

My goal would be to modify `doPostBack()` to save the information I need to `localStorage` before executing the rest of `doPostBack()` without changing it.

(Note: `doPostBack()` here looks incredibly simplistic, so I think I'm missing some information about how ASP.NET works here.  This is outside of the question though, unless it's relevant for what I'm trying to do.)

I was able to successfully modify `doPostBack()` in this way using Chrome Local Overrides to serve myself a local copy of the page on page load, instead of the server version.  But this only works for the first `doPostBack()` request.  After the first request, the server serves me new code.  Like with ViolentMonkey, the lack of a refresh trigger prevents Chrome Local Overrides from re-serving my local copy, and I'm served code without the `doPostBack()` modification.

So that's where I'm at.  I'll try adding a global listener like @wOxxOm suggested, and see where that gets me.

Comment: Add a global listener that runs before the site's one: addEventListener('change', yourFunc, **true**) and then call event.stopPropagation() in order to stop the site's listeners from seeing the event. You can also hook XMLHttpRequest prototype or `fetch` or `submit` event that's used by the site to send the data, there are many examples. For further assistance please show [MCVE](/help/mcve) or a link to the site.

Comment: @wOxxOm I updated the question with more detail.  It's not an MCVE though - I can't replicate the page functionality without access to the server code, and I don't want to share access to my company's inventory system online.  I'm going to look into what you suggested though, and I'll update with what I find out.

Comment: All you need is addEventListener for the `change` event and it'll work regardless of refreshing the page. Attach if globally (i.e. on `window` or `document`) and make sure your userscript matches the URL of the refreshed page. No need to override __doPostBack.

Comment: @wOxxOm I ended up finding another solution.  Just so you know, the `event.stopPropagation` did allow for me to programmatically fill out the form, but the changes wouldn't be reapplied to a new form once the first form was submitted.  I don't know if there's a solution to that as well, but I guess we don't have to investigate that anymore now.  Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Chrome extension called "Run Javascript" (has an elephant for it's logo), which runs the JavaScript code even on AJAX requests.

Link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/run-javascript/lmilalhkkdhfieeienjbiicclobibjao/

Answer (score -1):

I don't see how this is possible at all. You need to work with the people that created that web page.

Asp.net and the server side code will be EXTENSIVE .net code (c# or vb.net). Each of those events you trigger will set variables and server side session (or viewstate) values for the code behind to run.

That's how asp.net pages work. You post back, page travels up to server, THEN the .net code behind runs. That code will modify the page, modify controls, and modify the view state for that page. And after that code runs (say on a button click), then you client side will receive a whole new fresh page - that will blow out any JavaScript you try and inject. (you would have to re-inject each time). But, it gets worse, since quite of bit of that code behind also checks and often will NOT tolerate that the page settings have been messed with, and will be rejected.

About the only way to do this would be to write some desktop software, and that software would "house" or "host" a full "com" object copy of the web page, and you thus automate that given page. (and even then, you still fighting a losing battle).

Hint:
Web development, business logic, and a functional business applcation is NOT some simple markup and JavaScript (despite what that lame 2 week HTML course tells you).

This is a application, and  asp.net applcation. Trying to think of this as just some markup and JavaScript is actually quite silly here. It not how you write, or build business solutions for a company.

If you can't write and modify the code and the web server side of things then find out if that site has some kind of web api or whatever.

But, really - this is silly, and unless this is some simple college project, or some hacked up html page and some JavaScript? Forget this approach - you dealing with FAR too much server side and code behind on the server.

In fact, asp.net as noted has quite a bit built in features that check if the page being posted back been messed with, and you never really be sure that you set values and that the proper amounts of code behind that runs to setup row values, database primary key values and a WHOLE boatload of state values that are probably 100% saved in server side session() based class objects - and objects that are never exposed server side.

Tring to supposed modify or assume you can create or modify such a system with only client side tools is not going to work - its just not.

code behind runs, it re-processes the page with .net code and then sends the whole page back down - all with new state values etc. This is not some lame html + JavaScript, but is a full server side code driven system written in c# .net code.

Comment: Generally it's possible and rather trivial to implement as I noted in my comment under the question.

Comment: Well, if you think that you can perserve the page, and control round trips from the server? I don't see how you going to control the content being sent from the server - including that of client side js that will be present and sent from the server side. I find it hard to believe this can become a workable solution - especially for production code. I certainly would love to be shown and proven wrong here - really I would.

Comment: Userscripts can trivially intercept both the request and the response, then spoof/modify it so the server will see the modified data. Anyway, this discussion is fully moot without [MCVE](/help/mcve) as we don't even know what exactly the OP wants. Currently the question should be closed as it attracts opinion-based answers like this one.

Comment: But he not just modify data - and changing anything more than data on the page has very high chance of breaking the page. If page was 100% Ajax then ok, but that's doubt full. In most cases you then get a invalid postback or callback argument error unless that's been disabled. That why asp.net will validate the page - to prevent such changes client side. As noted I just don't think this is a valid approach to application software

Comment: No, the question describes only client-side automation so it doesn't matter how the server is implemented. This is a common task for userscripts that automate sites. It's possible to monkey-patch client-side code, it's possible to spoof data, it's possible to automate any client-side data submission. Anyway, this discussion is pointless without MCVE.

Comment: That is the problem - if this was only client side automation, then why and how is his js getting over written? Answer = his automation is causing post-backs and round trips - and each time you do that, you get a whole new fresh page from the server. That explains why and how his js code is getting overwritten each time he does some page operations - he is causing post-backs and round trips - and each time you get the original copy of js code and everything else on that page starts new and fresh each time. As I stated if this was just data - then fine, but postbacks are another matter.

Comment: it is entirely possible I am missing something here - but preventing the round trip from sending down fresh js code from the server seems to be the issue here.

Comment: The OP tried to change js code only as a means to intercept the data, but it's not necessary: there are multiple other methods of doing it as I mentioned in my comments.

Comment: The problem is more then just data. User hits next page or hit button on a gridview row. Each row button on that gv will have specific js generated for each row click. If you don't let that js code come down, then the page will not work correctly anymore.  Poster CLEAR states his js code is being replaced - and you quite much HAVE to allow that to occur, else the intended functionality of that page will not work anymore. So, some type of post-back MUST be occurring else no need for this question as to how to prevent such js code being replaced. Page receives MORE then just data to work.

Comment: He is scanning codes into that page, and then the server is responding with a fresh re-updated page - and that is the basic issue and problem. If the page was JUST receiving data, then fine - but it not - it running code on entry of data into those text boxes, and the server is THEN updating the page - and that includes js code to keep the correct functioning of the page. If you prevent he js code from being replaced in this context, then you going to break how the page works and what the code was designed to do.

Comment: My point is that there's no need to replace js. This is a typical task of automating client-side pages, which can be solved easily by a userscript. For the 6th time, this discussion in comments is completely moot and nonproductive without a real MCVE.

Comment: I am 100% in agreement with you then! Automating, and living with new updated js and markup that the server will no doubt send back to the client all the time? 100% agree with you. So, we are on the same page - to modify that js code one will simple will have to accept that interaction with the page WILL send new updated js code and markup often for each interaction. That's been my point all along and OP attempts to NOT allow the js code updates is a loosing battle. So, not a moot discussion - you basic saying 100% the same thing I am - you need to let the js change on that page.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I updated the question with more details on what I'm trying to accomplish.  I don't want to prevent the normal functionality of the page, I just want to be able to intercept the page whenever a `postBack` is made and insert JavaScript to automatically fill in the values of the fields from `localStorage`, then submit the form.  Unless you're saying that the entirety of the HTML content is sent back to the server and verified against what was served, and the page would be invalidated as a result? (When I did server logic, it was with PHP, and I never encountered this there.)